# Ubuntu 22.04 Java path not getting set

Tags: java, ubuntu-22.04

I followed the answers to previous questions for setting java path. I have added it in file `/etc/environment` as well as `~/.bashrc` file. When i run `echo $JAVA_HOME` i get the path as output but when i try to run java -version i get the output as java command is not recognised. What am i doing wrong?

```
sierra@sierra-pc:~$ cat ~/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac


# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export JAVA_HOME=/snap/openjdk/1465/jdk
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH








sierra@sierra-pc:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/snap/openjdk/1465/jdk
sierra@sierra-pc:~$ java
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.20.1+1-0ubuntu1~22.04, or
sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72build2
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless  # version 17.0.8.1+1~us1-0ubuntu1~22.04
sudo apt install openjdk-18-jre-headless  # version 18.0.2+9-2~22.04
sudo apt install openjdk-19-jre-headless  # version 19.0.2+7-0ubuntu3~22.0
```

Comment: Try turn on the new terminal and tried it again

Comment: I did, also tried system restart but nothing chamged

Comment: could you please give the output of `ls /snap/openjdk/1465/jdk`

Comment: Then try `cd /; grep -ir "java|jdk"` at

Comment: @dungxibo123 it seems the folder is 1495 and not 1465. It works now thanks for pointing it out. What I still dont understand is that earlier i had set the path as 1465 folder and was using java from terminal but yesterday I started facing the issue that java command not found and the folder 1465 no longer exists! how did it change to 1495, I only installed jdk 21 recently...

Comment: ... LoL, I have never met this case in my life =))))

Answer (score 1):

Setting an environment variable has never been so complicated for me. The syntax is quite straightforward, you can set environment variables in bash using the export keyword like this: `export NAME=VALUE`

So, setting your environment variable is as simple as this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/openjdk
```

Maybe installing Java as a snap is what is causing the issue, I personally never use snap packages so that is probably it but I'm not sure.